# Is there any way to specify two types as a function arg type in a Java?

Tags: java

I don't want to declare Object as a type for certain reasons, but I just need the compiler to check if the input belongs to any of the two types mentioned in the code. (Integer,Double)

```
public static Integer/Double on(Integer/Double a,Integer/Double b)
{
return a+b;
}
```

Is it possible without `instanceof` in Java (shortest syntax possible)?

Comment: Use `Generics` in java

Comment: Hey! Please be aware of that you are using an object oriented language, with inheritance, polymorphism and so on ... use those principles.

Comment: well both are Number.

Comment: I just updated my answer...I need it for a static methods...

Comment: @AhmetOZKESEK But I can't perform operations directly on it.

Comment: Can we do something like E extends ...,... in static methods?

Comment: You can declare two methods - overloaded signatures. One with Integer.. The other with Doubles. They can share the same name. The Java APIs are full of examples.. String.valueOf for example!

Comment: What is the goal here? How you want to use this method? Do you want to mix those types like `on(3.14, 2)`?

Comment: @Pshemo I would love to leave that on what the programmer who calls that function

Comment: @JGFMK Yes but I want to somehow write it in a single function as the function body might be long

Comment: @Sister of Stackoverflow, better use the largest value, a.doubleValue(), to perform operation. I mean return a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue(), does this make sense?

Comment: I want to return a Integer for a Integer Double for a Double and a Double when both the types are present...

Comment: @SisterofStackoverflow "as the body might be long" please show what you actually want to do. As it stands, two overloads is the correct approach.

Comment: Can you show the long method body that you are trying to avoid duplicating? For `Integer` and `Double`, duplicating code is almost unavoidable. What we can reduce is _how much_.

Comment: static Number oper(Number a, Number b, BiFunction<Number, Number, Number> calc) {
        //Integer ir = oper(10, 43.50, (a,b) -> a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue()).intValue();
        //Long lr = oper(14.32, 50, (a,b) -> a.doubleValue() - b.doubleValue()).longValue();
        
        return calc.apply(a, b);
    }

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do "something" for only `Integer` and `Double` types, and need to add instances of that type, and the body of the method is more complicated than just adding the parameters: use two overloads, and delegate to a private method:

```
static Integer on(Integer a, Integer b) {
  return on(a, b, Integer::sum);
}

static Double on(Double a, Double b) {
  return on(a, b, Double::sum);
}

private static <T> T on(T a, T b, BinaryOperator<T> sum) {
  // ... Something, using `sum.apply` to add things.
}
```

Callers (outside this class) can only invoke the Integer/Double overloads here. Generics won't directly allow you to restrict to specific types; all you can do is to restrict the visibility of the generic method.

Comment: Generics URL: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html  Binary Operator URL: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html (And as @Andy Turner pointed out in my deleted answer you need this otherwise a + b won't work as the plus operator wouldn't exists if you did a+b directly). Nice answer

Answer (score 2):

You could solve it like this:

```
static Double on(Double a, Double b) {
    return a+b;
}

static Integer on(Integer a, Integer b) {
    return on(a.doubleValue(), b.doubleValue()).intValue();
}

static void test() {
    System.out.println(on(1.0, 2.0).getClass());
    System.out.println(on(1, 2).getClass());
}
```

This will not work however if you try to call this with two primitives where one is an int and the other is a double:

```
static void test2() {
    System.out.println(on(1, 2.0).getClass()); // this doesn't compile
}
```

Comment: @SisterofStackoverflow this is not possible in a single function without resorting to `instanceof` checks. Please note that in my solution you write the complete code only once, the second method (`Integer on(Integer a, Integer b)`) is just a thin wrapper around the first one and doesn't change no matter how complex the first one gets.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create two overloaded method if you are using OOP.

One will be,

```
public static Integer on(Integer a,Integer b){

    return a+b;
}
```

Another will be,

```
public static Double on(Double a,Double b){

    return a+b;
}
```

Based on your input, either of the method will be invoked. And I think you want to get this kind of solution.

Comment: Actually my method body is longer than just adding two numbers

Comment: @SisterofStackoverflow it will help you get an answer if you actually show the problem.

Comment: Yes, it's better if you give at least outline of the problem.